# Rechart Bar Chart: show nothing except the bar? (fullwidth and fullheight?)

Tags: html, css, reactjs, charts, recharts

im trying to create a simple bar stacked graph using [Recharts](https://recharts.org/en-US/) but im having some trouble trying to reach the desired look and feel.

Basically I just need to show the bar (composed by different bars) and nothing else (no legend, axis, whatever, no margin nor paddings: the bars have to fillup the whole chart wrapper).

My code so far:

```
  const chartData = [
    {
      foo: 8,
      bar: 1,
      baz: 12,
      ext: 1,
      test: 55,
    },
  ];
...

<ResponsiveContainer height="100%" width="100%">
  <BarChart layout="vertical" data={chartData} margin={{ top: 0, right: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0 }}>
    <XAxis type="number" hide />
    <YAxis type="category" hide />
    <Bar dataKey="foo" stackId="a" fill="#f4f1de" barSize={40} />
    <Bar dataKey="bar" stackId="a" fill="#e07a5f" barSize={40} />
    <Bar dataKey="baz" stackId="a" fill="#3d405b" barSize={40} />
    <Bar dataKey="ext" stackId="a" fill="#81b29a" barSize={40} />
    <Bar dataKey="test" stackId="a" fill="#f2cc8f" barSize={40} />
  </BarChart>
</ResponsiveContainer>
```

And the result i get: [image: bar chart]

I need to remove the white (gray) space on the right and on the bottom.
Also, to be sure the size of the bars is respected (40px), I had to set the ResponsiveContainer's parent like to 150px, or the bars become really small (like 15 px hight)

Any idea?

(ps: i know for this chart could be easily done with plain css, but i need to use recharts)

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrapp the rechart's **ResponsiveContainer** on a container with your desired width and height. Then you need to specify the **Xaxis** and **YAxis** domain to adjust it to the desired height and width. You also need to define the **barCategoryGap** of **BarChart** component to "0%".

The code block should look something like this.

```
<ResponsiveContainer height={'100%'} width={"100%"}>
  <BarChart
    barCategoryGap="0%"
    layout="vertical"
    data={chartData}
    margin={{ top: 0, right: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0 }}
  >
    <XAxis type="number" hide domain={["dataMin", "dataMax"]} />
    <YAxis type="category" hide domain={["dataMin", "dataMax"]}/>
    <Bar dataKey="foo" stackId="a" fill="#f4f1de" />
    <Bar dataKey="bar" stackId="a" fill="#e07a5f" />
    <Bar dataKey="baz" stackId="a" fill="#3d405b" />
    <Bar dataKey="ext" stackId="a" fill="#81b29a" />
    <Bar dataKey="test" stackId="a" fill="#f2cc8f" />
  </BarChart>
</ResponsiveContainer>
```

You dont need the **barSize** property on the **Bar** component.

This is a working code sample of the chart.

[image: Edit fullWidth-barChart]